# Plotting non-parametric (E)CDF confidence envelopes for comparison

Tags: r, distributions, confidence-interval, nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have previously asked about a way to test whether two samples are drawn from the same distribution ([Non-parametric test if two samples are drawn from the same distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288416/non-parametric-test-if-two-samples-are-drawn-from-the-same-distribution)). I was very glad to learn about the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test. This seems excellent for hypothesis testing with p-values.

I am interested in generalizing this to a visual comparison of samples using confidence bands. I wonder if my idea is valid and, if so, how I can implement it with R, and if not, what a better approach might be.

The idea is to visually plot CDF confidence bands for each of *N* samples. This should show two things. First, the "tightness" of the confidence bands will suggest how adequate the sample sizes are for drawing inferences. Second, anywhere the confidence bands for a pair of samples do not overlap will indicate a significant difference in the KS-statistic, i.e. a point where one CDF seems to be "greater than" or "less than" another.

Does this make sense? I was hoping to find an example graph on Google Images, but the nearest I found is only one sample:

[image: ECDF with confidence band]

My graph would be similar, except I would show *N* samples and look for blank spaces between the confidence bands.

If indeed this sounds reasonable, then I have a few specific questions:

- Is this a well-known technique? (Reference to a description?)
- How should I compute the CDF confidence bands? (Is there an R package that I should use?)
- How valid is the visual comparison of confidence bands? (If I plot two samples, how closely will a non-overlapping point correspond with a significant result from the KS test?)
- What pitfalls should I consider when comparing more than two samples? (Should I adjust the parameters of my confidence bands in the spirit of the Bonferroni correction?) Note: I am okay with the comparison being more informal than a p-value.

Thanks!

### UPDATE

I found an example of the kind of graph that I have in mind now:

[image: graph]

I will try to work out how to create such a graphic using ggplot2 and the ecdf.ksCI() function recommended in the comment.

### UPDATE 2

Thank you for the answer below. I was able to generate my graph, and here is a sample. I am pleased!

[image: CDF with confidence bands]

Comment: See:   https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/036643.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I read a presentation (http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/621/F10/notes/8-26.pdf) that talks about the difference between _pointwise confidence intervals_ verses _confidence bands/envelopes_ for whole CDFs. They seem to advocate the latter as being more appropriate. Is this relevant to the discussion? (Is ecdf.ksCI providing a pointwise confidence interval and will this have practical consequences e.g. more type I/II errors?)

Comment: I have tested the ecdf.ksCI function now. It's pretty neat. Can it also somehow display _N_ samples together for comparison? (Or is there a straightforward way to adapt it to ggplot2 and geom_ribbon?)

Comment: You would have to get the code for the function and use it as a starting point. As it is written now it only produces the plot, it returns nothing.

Comment: Could you share the code and data to reproduce the Updated 2's chart?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, and invert it to get a confidence band. Let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ be iid observations from some continuous distribution function $F$.  Then the KS test statistic is given by
$$
    D_n = \sup_x \mid \hat{F}_ n(x)-F_0(x) \mid = 
    \max_{i=1,2,\dotsc,n} \max \{\frac{i}{n}-F_0(x_{(i)}),F_0(x_{(i)})-\frac{i-1}{n} \}
$$
where $x_{(1)} \le \dotso \le x_{(n)}$ is the order statistics. What is remarkable is that the distribution of $D_n$ do not depend on the assumed null distribution $F_0$ (which must be prespecified). Now we can invert this hypothesis test to get a confidence band. WE can calculate
$$
P_{F_0}(D_n \le d) = P_{F_0}( \sup_x \mid \hat{F}_ n(x)-F_0(x) \mid \le d) = \\ P_{F_0}( \hat{F}_n(x)-d \le F_0(x) \le \hat{F}_n(x)+d, \quad \text{for all $x$})
$$
this calculation shows that this is indeed a simultaneous confidence band, valid simultaneously for all $x$.

An implementation of this can be found in the R package (on CRAN) `sfsmisc`, in the function `ecdf.ksCI`.  (Disclaimer: That was originally my code).  An example:

[image: Plot of ecdf by R, package sfsmisc]

R code:

```r
library(sfsmisc)
set.seed(7*11*13)
ecdf.ksCI( rchisq(50,3), main="ECDF, sample from chisq with 3 df")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Reading the source code of the `ecdf.ksCI` function was very instructive and lead me to an implementation that suits my own purposes.

Comment: That's very interesting. As constructing a $(1-\alpha)$ confidence band requires setting $d$ to the $(1-\alpha)$ quantile of the Kolmogorov distribution, I would suggest to add your code for computing this quantile. The code can be found here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/036643.html, but this link may become stalled, so it would be useful to include the code it in the answer.