# Confidence bounds for an ECDF

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, python, matlab

I'm attempting to create an ECDF (and a confidence bound) from data in Python. I can generate the ECDF fairly easily with `numpy` by sorting and using `linspace`. However, I'm not entirely certain what the appropriate confidence bounds are, and there don't seem to be any built-in libraries that calculate the bounds (`statsmodels` seems to just give the ECDF).

If I want a *point-wise* confidence bound of $1-\alpha$ is it appropriate to use the [DKW inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality#Building_CDF_bands) to calculate my region with

$$C_n(\alpha) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)} \,,$$

where $n$ is the number of observations in my sample? Thus if $F(x)$ is my ECDF, my upper and lower bounds would be

$$\mathrm{UB}(x) = \min\left(1,  F(x)+C_n(\alpha)\right)$$
$$\mathrm{LB}(x) = \max\left(0,  F(x)-C_n(\alpha)\right)$$

MATLAB has a built-in function [ECDF](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html), but I didn't have much luck understanding how to apply Greenwood's Formula (referenced at the bottom) to generate the bounds.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298290/plotting-non-parametric-ecdef-confidence-envelopes-for-comparison and my comments there. Look at the code of ecdf.ksCI in CRAN package sfsmisc. That code is simple (I wrote it ...) so should be easy to translate to python ...

Comment: What is not entirely clear is that you ask for *point-wise* bounds, but suggest to use an inequality, [DKW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality), that is mostly employed to find *simultaneous* confidence bounds. Please note: Greenwood's approach is point-wise.

Comment: @Jim So would applying that method above just be incorrect, or would it instead give me the simultaneous confidence bound?

Comment: It would give you the simultaneous one. Which is fine if that's what you're after. But note that a simultaneous CI is wider than a point-wise one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Matlab's console type:

```
edit ecdf
```

It opens the source code in the editor.

Go to line 194:

```
if nargout>2 || (nargout==0 && isequal(bounds,'on'))
```

This is the start of the code block that calculates the lower - and upper (confidence) bounds: `[Flo, Fup]`. The code block is 30 lines long and pretty straightforward. Posted below for your convenience:

```matlab
if nargout>2 || (nargout==0 && isequal(bounds,'on'))
     % Get standard error of requested function
     if cdf_sf % 'cdf' or 'survivor'
         se = NaN(size(D));
         if N(end)==D(end)
            t = 1:length(N)-1;
         else
            t = 1:length(N);
         end
         se(t) = S(t) .* sqrt(cumsum(D(t) ./ (N(t) .* (N(t)-D(t))))); % <--- line 203
     else % 'cumhazard'
         se = sqrt(cumsum(D ./ (N .* N)));
     end

     % Get confidence limits
     zalpha = -norminv(alpha/2);
     halfwidth = zalpha*se;
     Flo = max(0, Func - halfwidth);
     Flo(isnan(halfwidth)) = NaN; % max drops NaNs, put them back
     if cdf_sf % 'cdf' or 'survivor'
         Fup = min(1, Func + halfwidth);
         Fup(isnan(halfwidth)) = NaN; % max drops NaNs
     else % 'cumhazard'
         Fup = Func + halfwidth; % no restriction on upper limit
     end
         Flo = [NaN; Flo];
         Fup = [NaN; Fup];
else 
     Flo = [];
     Fup = [];
end
```

The square root of Greenwood's formula, i.e.

$$ S(t) \sqrt{\sum_{t_i < T} \frac{d_i}{r_i(r_i - d_i)}} \,, $$

is implemented in line 203 as:

```
se(t) = S(t) .* sqrt(cumsum(D(t) ./ (N(t) .* (N(t)-D(t)))));
```

Can you take it from here? Let me know.