# How to plot a confidence band around the ecdf in the form (ecdf-b, ecdf+b) for a certain b in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I need to plot a confidence band around my ecdf. I calculated a value b and I basically just need to plot ecdf+b and ecdf-b but R doesnt let me do that. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298290/plotting-non-parametric-ecdef-confidence-envelopes-for-comparison    which have R code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Note that `ecdf` yields a function in R. (Also note that the code makes no claim to the bands reporting something "useful"; `b` is completely arbitrary.)

```
x <- rnorm(100)
Fn <- ecdf(x) 
plot(Fn, col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
b <- .1
lines(sort(x), Fn(sort(x))+b, col="salmon", lwd=2)
lines(sort(x), Fn(sort(x))-b, col="salmon", lwd=2)
```

[image]